# API has been failing with CORS errors since 11/13

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

Other posts on the topic

- [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391242/se-api-is-randomly-responding-with-site-is-required-errors-and-now-cors-errors)
- [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8356/after-successfully-retrieving-180-pages-the-api-gracelessly-semi-silently-fai)

The API is no longer sending [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers after 180 calls

> You can replicate it from any browser using the code below.
>
> Every time I run it, it fetches 180 pages at an average rate of 5.51 calls per second.
>
> On the 181st call I get: Cross-Origin Request Blocked

This affects all API calls to all sites and is wreaking havoc with multiple userscripts that rely on the API, but get a CORS error and will not process the response.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks for reporting! A fix for this was just deployed, and the CORS headers are getting sent again.

Comment: Wow! That was fast from when this was reported here on MSE! Thanks for getting it done!

Comment: I've written up a more detailed answer on SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391352/155005

Comment: Just FYI: using the code in [this Stack Apps answer](https://stackapps.com/a/8357/29529) to test indicates that the change made to resolve the larger, more important issue did not resolve the problem reported in the [Stack Apps bug report from a few months ago](https://stackapps.com/q/8356/29529). Note: please see my last comment on the answer I linked for a complication to testing (i.e. I did not encounter the problem the second time I tested, but with a `key` value in the requests).