# The SE API fails with a CORS error when hitting the rate-limit

Tags: bug, api, rate-limiting, throttling

I'm experiencing the same/similar problem as described in [API has been failing with CORS errors since 11/13](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338345/)

When I run the below stack-snippet that basically makes various calls to the SE API, I'm greeted with a CORS error once I run into the throttle limit of I think the HA-proxy. I'm happy to handle the throttle and back-off a lot but it would help if I could get the real HTTP error code.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users...' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

For those who want to reproduce this, the included code-snippet can be run while you watch the Developer Console. **WARNING: This code will IP address throttle your connection to the SE network so if you run it and hit the throttle, you might not be able to post for a few minutes**

Can this be looked at and if possible be fixed so the proper headers are sent for https://api.stackexchange.com/2.x/ routes despite being in a throttled error condition?

---

I do know this code doesn't honor the `backoff` parameter but trust me, in the actual code I do handle backoff and that isn't enough to always steer clear from this error. In this sense this is a minimal, complete, verifiable example. Not a sane example.

```js
var api = {
  url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/',
  endpoint: 'questions/featured',
  params: {
    site: 'stackoverflow',
    pagesize: 100,
    order: 'desc',
    sort: 'activity',
    Filter: '!iCF4LsDYJt6oT_Y1qKBCOv',
    key: 'VyQN2SnsdXDfeiBS9*ZsEg(('
    }
  };

function createUrl(ap) {
  var ep = ap.url + ap.endpoint +'?',
     nv = [];
  if (ap.params) {
    for(var p in ap.params) {
      if (ap.params.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
           nv.push(p + '=' + ap.params[p]);
      }
    }
  }
  // console.log(ep + nv.join('&'));
  return ep + nv.join('&');
}

function createSitesUrl() {
  return createUrl(
    { url: api.url,
      endpoint: 'sites',
      params: {
        pagesize: 500,
        key: api.params.key,
        filter: '!*l7_tSmzy1mF3bw9odQw*8ur' }
     });
}

function createUserFeaturedUrl(userid, site) {
  return createUrl(
    { url: api.url,
      endpoint: 'users/'+ userid + '/questions/featured',
      params: {
        site: site,
        pagesize: 100,
        key: api.params.key,
        filter: '!*7PmgCF3rY3WihzNKHz4jURFN9X6' }
     });
}

function createInfoUrl(site) {
  return createUrl(
    { url: api.url,
      endpoint: 'info',
      params: {
        site: site,
        key: api.params.key,
        filter: '!39qVOEzAjeqnKS5bl7_puf_.GSZJG' }
     });
}

function createAccountsUrl(accountid) {
  return createUrl(
    { url: api.url,
      endpoint: 'users/'+ accountid + '/associated',
      params: {
        pagesize: 100,
        key: api.params.key,
        filter: '!w*vp4lVBIX453e.b5Y' }
     });
}

// used when we are good to call
function get(url, callback) {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', url);
   xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
     var data;
     if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
       data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
       callback(data);
     } else {
       console.log('readystate and status ', xhr.readyState, xhr.status);
     }
  });

  xhr.addEventListener('error', function(err) {
    console.log('error for ', url, err, xhr.status);
    document.getElementById('err').textContent=xhr.status + xhr.statusText;
    console.log('error after nasty error ', err);
  });

  xhr.addEventListener('abort', function() {
    console.log('abort for ', url, xhr.status);
  });
  xhr.send();
}

function loadUserFeatured(userid, site) {
   console.log('loadUserFeatured', userid, site);
   get(createUserFeaturedUrl(userid, site.api_site_parameter), function(data) {
     data.items.forEach( function(item) {
         console.log(item);
     });
  });
}


function loadUserFromAccount(item) {
  console.log('loadUserFromAccount', item);
  var uid = item.user_id;
  var site = item.site_url.replace('https://','');
  get(createInfoUrl(site), function(data) {
    loadUserFeatured(uid, data.items[0].site);
  });
}

function loadAccounts(accountId) {
  console.log('loadAccounts', accountId);
  get(createAccountsUrl(accountId), function(data) {
    data.items.forEach( function(item) {
       loadUserFromAccount(item);
    });
  });
}

loadAccounts(267077);  // network profile with lots of accounts
```

```html
Caution! When you run this you will flood the SE servers with many, many calls. They might hate you. So much, you'll be IP blocked.
<div id='err'></div>
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackapps.com/q/9027